# New Maven dependency not put in Eclipse class path until I run eclipse:eclipse

Tags: maven, classpath, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse `.classpath` file  adds a line for every Maven dependency that the project needs. If I update my `pom.xml` file with a new dependency, Eclipse doesn't find this dependency and only the way to make it find it is to run `eclipse:eclipse`. After running `eclipse:eclipse` the eclipse `.classpath` file has new entries for new dependencies.

Comment: On my maven project in eclipse I can right click it and select Maven -> Update Project. Does yours have that?

Comment: I tried  Maven -> Update Project  , nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This'll be due to which maven plugin you're using for Eclipse. I've had success with https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ in the past.

Also, if it is an option for you, IntelliJ IDEA Community edition works very well with Maven out of the box and all the other popular build tools too. I set keybindings to Eclipse (also built-in) for an easy transition.